# Question about grouping ambiguity when parsing sentences with many *de* words

Tags: prépositions, de

OSAP (**Ontario Student Assistance Program**) is the English name of my province's student loans program.

The French name is RAFEO (**Regime d'aide financière aux étudiantes et étudiants de l'Ontario**).

"Ontario Student Assistance Program" is a little bit ambiguous. For example, does the word "Ontario" describe the Program, or does "Ontario" describe the Students? (ie, is it a Student Assistance Program that is Ontarian, or is it an Assistance Program for Ontario Students?)

(Indeed, there is more ambiguity: is it an Assistance Program for Ontario Students, or is it a Program for [ [Ontario Student] Assistance] )? )

My question: is it true that the French name is completely unambiguous?
That is, that it is a Program for [financial aid to [students who live in Ontario]]? (so, Ontario describes the students, not the Program?)

---

Edited to add

Question #2: If there is a group of words that act like a noun (such as `Regime d'aide financière aux étudiantes et étudiants de l'Ontario`), where there are many "de" and "à" words, what are the rules that group the adjectives and nouns together?

Question #3: Can you give me somoe examples of French sentences that use the rules explained in the answer to Question #2, but still have ambiguity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in French the name is not ambiguous.

If Ontario was to describe the Program then it would have been written differently.

For example, if the name was `Regime d'aide financière étudiante de l'Ontario` then "étudiante" is adjective of the assistance and Ontario would be describing the program.

Same if it was written `Regime d'aide financière de l'Ontario aux étudiantes et étudiants`

Comment: You say the French name is "far less ambiguous". It is in fact completely without ambiguity, or is there still some ambiguity in it?

Comment: Also, suppose Ontario were to describe the program. Would the following sentence be one way to say this: `Regime de l'Ontario d'aide financière aux étudiantes et étudiants`?

Comment: 3) Also, with your first sentence (`Regime d'aide financière étudiante de l'Ontario`), you say that Ontario is describing "Regime". How come Ontario is not instead describing "aide"?

Comment: Ontario is describing the whole "Regime d'aide financière ". That's why I said program. And `Regime de l'Ontario d'aide financière aux étudiantes et étudiants` does not work. Like in English there is an order to adjectives in French.

Comment: In similar sentences there would still be some ambiguity: « [regime d'aide] financière » or « regime [d'aide financière] » ? In this sentence we know it must be the second one because *regime* is masculine, *aide* is feminine, and the adjective has feminine agreement. But if both nouns were the same gender it would be ambiguous.